# What's the name of a closure of a complement of a closed halfspace?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Let $A$ be a closed half-space of an affine space. What's the name of $cl(A')$? I was tentatively using the name "conjugate", but I don't know if its correct.

Comment: What do you mean by $A'$?

Comment: A complement of $A$, as stated in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it the "complementary half-space" (as used, e.g., [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=JvFGDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA464&lpg=PA464&dq=%22complementary+half-space%22&source=bl&ots=Nn-rgdKJTv&sig=UXAVb89ddI15HDSwaqTkmjbjIaU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb1YH9xLvdAhWh8YMKHSN5CjMQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22complementary%20half-space%22&f=false) or [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=aoMreDT_DwcC&pg=PA338&lpg=PA338&dq=%22complementary+half-space%22&source=bl&ots=ovSrQExczl&sig=MqkOvIaxbMTX7bYOBr8EvOJtcoY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb1YH9xLvdAhWh8YMKHSN5CjMQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22complementary%20half-space%22&f=false)). It might be worth specifically calling out that you're taking the *closed* complementary half-space, or specifically writing down that you're turning $a^{\mathsf T}x \le b$ into $a^{\mathsf T}x \ge b$, just to be clear - but it's not unusual terminology.

The word "conjugate" has [a specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) in convex analysis, so if you were to use it, I'd assume you were talking about something like the dual cone.

Comment: It's a bit disappointing TBH, but thanks